# Integration a trigonometric expression

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How would you evaluate the following indefinite integral?

$$ \int \frac {\ln{(x)} \cdot \cos{(x)}}{\sin^2 {(x)}} dx $$

Comment: ambiguos, please add brackets.

Comment: I have added brackets

Comment: OK so it is (ln(x))*(cos(x)) and not ln(x*cos(x))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int \ln x\csc x\cot x {\rm d}x=-\ln x\csc x-\int \frac1x(-\csc x){\rm d}x\\
=-\ln x\csc x+\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{x\sin x}$$
And I do not think the second term having a closed form. I have another idea but that's really unnecessary:
$$\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{x\sin x}=-4\int\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty} \frac{(2ix)^k B_{k+2}\left(\frac12\right)}{(k+2)!}{\rm d}x=-4\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty} \frac{(2ix)^{k+1} B_{k+2}\left(\frac12\right)}{2i(k+2)!}$$

---

$$\int \frac{\ln x\cos x}{\sin^2x} {\rm d}x\stackrel{u=\sin x}=\int\frac{\ln \arcsin u}{u^2}{\rm d}u$$

And probably this proceeds nowhere into standard mathematical functions.

Comment: If we were to use substitution method, do u think it would have been possible that way?

Comment: @MonK see edit.

Comment: So both cases, there is not result?

Comment: So does this integral not have a closed form?

Comment: @Kinhu I don't think so, but where did you got it?

Comment: A friend gave it to me, but it turns out he miscommunicated the problem to me. I was wondering whether the "wrong" problem can still be solved, so I posted it here, after my integration  by parts method got very messy.